# Highcharts Hyper Link on xaxis labels are not enabled by default

Tags: highcharts

In this `demo`http://jsfiddle.net/0yrsp04a/1/ why hyper links are not enabled by default on the xaxis labels (07/22/2015 and 07/23/2015).

Comment: As it is a drill down report, the xaxis labels should be click able.

Comment: The minRange parameter seems to cause that issue. Remove that and then seems to working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/0yrsp04a/11/